# How to only get random letters and not symbols

Tags: python, function, alphabetical

I am trying to make a small Hangman program with unlimited trials. I think I finished building the program, but one problem is when the text includes symbols (like a period (.) for example). I tried multiple ways to only get letters out from a given file, but that didn't work.. Can anyone please help me out??

**My code**

```
fr = input("What file would you like to open: ")
f = open(fr, 'r')
text = f.read()
x = 0
textsplit = text.split()
guess_list = ''



import random
rand_letter = random.choice(textsplit)

for i in range(len(rand_letter)):
    print ('*', end = '')
print ()
while x == 0:
    guess = input("Guess a character: ")
    guess_list += guess
    if guess not in rand_letter:
        print("You're wrong bro")
    else:
        for char in rand_letter:
            if char in guess_list:
                print (char, end = ''),

            if char not in guess_list:
                print('*', end = ''),
    if guess_list == rand_letter:
        break
```

What I want to solve (example):[image]

The . in the "father." was actually pretty tough to guess, so I want to remove the symbols and only leave the alphabets.

Any help/advice/comment would be appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it with regex:

```py
import re

text = "father."
text = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", text)

"""
text: 'father'
"""
```

(This is if you want to include numbers and spaces too)
If you didn't want spaces, remove the `\s` and if you didn't want numbers, you can remove the `\w` and replace it with `a-zA-Z`.

Here's an example without using regex

```py
text = "father."
allowed = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ")

text = ''.join(c for c in text if c in allowed)

"""
text: 'father'
"""
```

Here, you can add any allowed characters to the `allowed` variable. I've made it a set for faster computation.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to filter the string you try to guess with this code which select only the letters in a string :

```
YOUR_STRING = ''.join(x for x in YOUR_STRING if x.isalpha())
```

With YOUR_STRING being rand_letter here.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This code works perfectly but both of the answers worked great so I just had to go with the faster one. Thank you so much though :)